# Hacer dos consultas en una sola línea SQL en PHPMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una BD en un servidor a la que accedo desde phpmyAdmin, quiero hacer una consulta múltiple y he escrito esta consulta de 3 líneas:

```
SELECT u.IDUsuario,`Nombre` FROM `usuarios` u JOIN `salas` s ON u.IDUsuario = s.UsuarioRecv WHERE s.UsuarioRem = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT u.IDUsuario,`Nombre` FROM `usuarios` u JOIN `salas` s ON u.IDUsuario = s.UsuarioRecv WHERE s.UsuarioRecv = 2
```

Esto me da la respuesta esperada.

Si lo junto en una sola línea queda de esta manera:

```
SELECT u.IDUsuario,`Nombre` FROM `usuarios` u JOIN `salas` s ON u.IDUsuario = s.UsuarioRecv WHERE s.UsuarioRem = 2; UNION ALL; SELECT u.IDUsuario,`Nombre` FROM `usuarios` u JOIN `salas` s ON u.IDUsuario = s.UsuarioRecv WHERE s.UsuarioRecv = 2
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
UNION ALL
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'UNION ALL' en la linea 1
```

¿Por qué?

Comment: Porque pones `;` antes y después de `UNION ALL`, lo cual crea un error de sintaxis. Pero me pregunto ¿por qué no haces una consulta con `JOIN`, prescindiendo de `UNION ALL`? ¿Qué es lo que esperas obtener?

Comment: si estoy de acuerdo contigo, se debería de usar una o otra, no las dos juntas, a mi parecer seria mas optimo utilizar únicamente la sentencia `UNION ALL`

Comment: Que pasaría si agregas esto `OR s.UsuarioRecv = 2` al final de la cláusula `WHERE` en el primer query? Creo, _con temor a equivocarme_, que no sería necesario hacer uso de `UNION ALL` ni del segundo query.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la manera, lo que ocurría es que para hacerlo de la manera que quería, debo añadirle paréntesis de esta manera:

```
(SELECT u.IDUsuario,`Nombre` FROM `usuarios` u JOIN `salas` s ON u.IDUsuario = s.UsuarioRecv WHERE s.UsuarioRem = 2) UNION ALL(SELECT u.IDUsuario,`Nombre` FROM `usuarios` u JOIN `salas` s ON u.IDUsuario = s.UsuarioRecv WHERE s.UsuarioRecv = ?)
```